# To get spans text content

Tags: javascript, html

I am able to get the divs style property transform

Html

```
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" _ngcontent-c6="" appdropzone="" 
   appmovablearea="" class="dropzone" id="toget" ng-reflect-ng-style=" 
   [object Object]" style="width: 100%;
   background-image: url(&quot;data:image/jpeg;base64,/9//2Q==&quot;);
   background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center; 
   background-size: 100% 100%; border: 1px solid black; height: 340px;">

  <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": " 502 "
  }-->

 <div _ngcontent-c6="" appmovable="" class="box draggable movable ng-star- 
  inserted"
  ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" touch-action="none" 
  style="transform: translateX(196%) translateY(109.6%);">

  502

  <span _ngcontent-c6="" style="display: none">196.00003051757812</span>
  <span _ngcontent-c6="" style="display: none">109.5999755859375</span>

 </div>

 <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": ""
 }-->

 </div>
```

The code

```
 const floorImagePlanConatiner = document.createElement("div");
            floorImagePlanConatiner.innerHTML = floorImage;
            floorImagePlanConatiner.querySelectorAll("div")
                .forEach(element => {
                    this.droppeditem = [];
                    if(element.style.transform)
                        floor.droppeditem.
                        push(element.childNodes[0].textContent);                   
     });
```

This html element I am getting from backend response which I assign to html div and iterate over. How can I get span content texts. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried getting array of span elements with **document.querySelectorAll**?
Then you can iterate over them to get text contents.

Comment: I have 2 requirements to access div style transform property and all the span text may be 1 or 2 or  more, so I am able to do the 1st requirement the style transform property with above code, how can I read span text as well along with the 1st style thing

Answer (score 1):

First you have to iterate through all `<div>` and iterate trough their children (`<span>`) to get their text content.

This code will do so:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(div => {
  div.querySelectorAll('span')
    .forEach(span => console.log(span.textContent));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer , so it will get me the transform property as well as span text content right

Comment: @Enthu first `forEach(div)` will give you `transform` property via `div.style`. Second `forEach(span)` all children `span` with their textContent.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll('div span')` to get all `<span>` elements.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('div div').forEach(div => {
  console.log(div.style.transform);
  div.querySelectorAll('span').forEach(span => {
    console.log(span.textContent);
  });
});
```

```html
<div>
  <div style="transform: translateX(196%) translateY(109.6%);">
    <span>196.00003051757812</span>
    <span>109.5999755859375</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks as I said I also want to get the div style transform property which I am already getting so inside the span's parent div I already have a code doing foreach , using that itself how can I access span's textcontent

Comment: Hi how can I get 502 value also , becoz when I try div.textContent , it gives all three value of the div + span  502 196.00003051757812109.5999755859375

Comment: And the foreach loop is also runnig 2times